# Displaying Window on Logon Screen Using C# in Windows XP

Tags: c#, windows-xp, service, desktop, winlogon

I am trying to create a service with C# that launches a process that can be displayed on the Windows XP Logon screen.

I found some code that is doing this in C++.  The C++ code is for a service that creates another process with STARTUPINFO.lpDesktop set to "WinSta0\WinLogon".  The created process is then displayed to the Windows Logon Screen.  I can't seem to find a way to specify the 'desktop' of a new process in C# using System.Diagnostic.Process class.

Does anyone know how to do this with C#?

Comment: Could you share your XP code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to call the C++ Win32 API function CreateProcess from kernel32.dll from the C# code.  This site was very helpful in getting the correct function signature for C#:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateProcess.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll have to write it in C++, compile that to a DLL and then call the DLL from your managed code.